# I cant get rollup to compile properly when using dynamic imports and crypto-js in my svelte web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, bundling-and-minification, rollup

I recently tried to codesplit my svelte web app for each page, but I haven't been able to get it to work while using the crypto-js package. If i remove the package everything works. The js compiles with the line `import "crypto"`, and that causes the browser to error and not to work.

**rollup.config.js**

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import { config } from "dotenv"
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve() {
    let server;
    
    function toExit() {
        if (server) server.kill(0);
    }

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (server) return;
            server = require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                shell: true
            });

            process.on('SIGTERM', toExit);
            process.on('exit', toExit);
        }
    };
}
let envVar = {}
Object.entries(config().parsed).map(([prop, value]) => {
    if (prop.startsWith("APP")) envVar[prop] = value
});

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: !production,
        format: 'esm',
        name: 'app',
        dir: 'public/build',
    },
    plugins: [
        json(),
        replace({
            __myapp: JSON.stringify({
                env: envVar
            }),
        }),
        svelte({
            // enable run-time checks when not in production
            dev: !production,
            // we'll extract any component CSS out into
            // a separate file - better for performance
            css: css => {
                css.write('bundle.css');
            }
        }),
        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
        commonjs({
            transformMixedEsModules:true,
            sourceMap: !production,
        }),
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte'],
            preferBuiltins: false
        }),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

**Browser Error**
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "crypto". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

**main.js**

```
(function(l, r) { if (l.getElementById('livereloadscript')) return; r = l.createElement('script'); r.async = 1; r.src = '//' + (window.location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1'; r.id = 'livereloadscript'; l.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(r) })(window.document);
export { ao as default } from './main-d2838af7.js';
import 'crypto';
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

Comment: Can you share the code of the files that _use_ the crypto package (just the imports & extension of the files skills be enough)? Note in passing: the compiled code you've shared is a dev build, not prod, so that's what we will be debugging here.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue after updating

Comment: See answers on [this similar post perhaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66158547/6882617)

Comment: I saw that answer. That's not what I'm looking for as it doesn't actually solve the issue. For example I've found many react packages use [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and somehow they manage to run but they don't given the build steps above. So the question is, what needs to be added to the build steps above to get them to work given that they work elsewhere. If you look at that package, you'll see it has 50k dependents. You can see [this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74232036/how-to-get-rollup-to-deal-with-node-based-libraries-in-the-browser)

Comment: Maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74232036/how-to-get-rollup-to-deal-with-node-based-libraries-in-the-browser/74280287#74280287) might help?

Answer (score 2):

Using `crypto-js` should just work.

If you download a ZIP from an empty [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/) and just add the `crypto-js` package, it will be compiled without any `import "crypto";` statements. There is an internal fallback mechanism that will resolve to using the the browser-native crypto module.

```js
/**
 * CryptoJS core components.
 */
var CryptoJS = CryptoJS || (function (Math, undefined$1) {

    var crypto;

    // Native crypto from window (Browser)
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.crypto) {
        crypto = window.crypto;
    }

    // ...
```

I tested it with a dynamic import and ESM output as well:

```
<!-- App.svelte -->
<div class="content">
    {#await import('crypto-js') then cryptoJs}
        {cryptoJs.default.SHA256('hello')}
    {/await}
</div>
```

Adjusted config for ESM and to support chunks (requires output directory):

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve()
{
    let server;

    function toExit()
    {
        if (server) server.kill(0);
    }

    return {
        writeBundle()
        {
            if (server) return;
            server = require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                shell: true
            });

            process.on('SIGTERM', toExit);
            process.on('exit', toExit);
        }
    };
}

/** @type {import('rollup').RollupOptions} */
export default {
    input: {
        bundle: 'src/main.js',
    },
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'esm',
        name: 'app',
        dir: 'public/build',
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            compilerOptions: {
                dev: !production
            }
        }),
        css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte'],
        }),
        commonjs(),
        !production && serve(),
        !production && livereload('public'),
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    },
};
```