# How do I import crypto in Svelte?

Tags: node.js, svelte, rollup, rollupjs

I created a basic svelte project (it uses rollup). I want to import a native library, crypto into the project like so.

```
// src/lib/encrypt.js

import { randomBytes } from "crypto";

const encrypt = () => {
  return randomBytes(4);
};

export { encrypt };
```

and import this into a svelte file like so,

```
// src/App.svelte
<script>
    import {encrypt} from './lib/encrypt';
</script>

<main>
    <p>{encrypt()}</p>
</main>
```

Doing so, yields,

```
Uncaught TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function
    at encrypt (encrypt.js:4)
    at Object.create [as c] (App.svelte:9)
    at init (index.mjs:1496)
    at new App (App.svelte:3)
    at main.js:3
```

How do I enable crypto to work for my scenario?

Note:
This probably has something to do with the way rollup works. Upon some researching, I found that `rollup-plugin-node-builtins` is used to load native modules. This didn't seem to work either. I tried configuring the rollup.config.js

```
// rollup.config.js
import svelte from "rollup-plugin-svelte";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import livereload from "rollup-plugin-livereload";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import css from "rollup-plugin-css-only";
import preprocess from "svelte-preprocess";
import builtins from "rollup-plugin-node-builtins";

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve() {
  let server;

  function toExit() {
    if (server) server.kill(0);
  }

  return {
    writeBundle() {
      if (server) return;
      server = require("child_process").spawn(
        "npm",
        ["run", "start", "--", "--dev"],
        {
          stdio: ["ignore", "inherit", "inherit"],
          shell: true,
        }
      );

      process.on("SIGTERM", toExit);
      process.on("exit", toExit);
    },
  };
}

export default {
  input: "src/main.js",
  output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: "iife",
    name: "app",
    file: "public/build/bundle.js",
  },

  plugins: [
    svelte({
      preprocess: preprocess(),
      compilerOptions: {
        // enable run-time checks when not in production
        dev: !production,
      },
    }),
    css({ output: "bundle.css" }),
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      dedupe: ["svelte"],
    }),
    builtins({ crypto: true }),
    commonjs(),
    !production && serve(),
    !production && livereload("public"),
    production && terser(),
  ],
  watch: {
    clearScreen: false,
  },
};
```

This results in,

```
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crypto` is a Node package intended to be run on the server and is tricky to run in the browser. rollup-plugin-node-builtins seems to be [deprecated](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/rollup-plugin-node-builtins/issues/65). Its [successor](https://github.com/ionic-team/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills) states in the README that shimming the crypto package likely won't work:

> Crypto is not shimmed and and we just provide the commonjs one from browserify and it will likely not work, if you really want it please pass {crypto: true} as an option.

You may need to find an alternative package that is intended to be used in the browser. Depending on your use case, you could also look into the native [web crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto).

Comment: Thank you for this :)  will look into the web crypto api.

Answer (score 0):

You might like crypto-wraps

https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-wraps

With little change in your app code, you can run it in the browser or in node.js There is a lib/ for node. And, a client/ for the browser.

This just makes dealing with crypto-subtle a little easier than straight on. I will be adding elliptic derived keys in a couple of days. And, I am thinking about what kinds of svelte components might be nice for focusing on crypto.